# how to refresh a dropdown list without a a submit in Symfony

Tags: symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I need to refresh a drop down list to display a session value after the filtering option is selected by another drop down. how can I do it?

Comment: Do you program with javascript?

Comment: Yes I am coding with javascript and Im trying to use a onchange event from the form to the template. seems to me that I can't apply the event.

Answer (score 0):

You need to represent your selected values and the combination of values in some kind of structured format. E.g.

```
    var names = {
        "Male": ["Byron", "William", "Samuel"],
        "Female": ["Anne", "Charlotte", "Emily"]
    }
```

Then you can use this information in the below fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/vYfRX/